# subprocess poll() returning wrong value

Tags: python, subprocess

I am starting a process and storing it in a variable:

```
 self.wpa_sup=subprocess.Popen(["/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant", "-Dnl80211,wext", "-i",self.linux_iface, "-c", "/etc/wpa_supplicant_%s.conf"%self.name, "-s"], 
                stdout=open('/dev/null','w'),  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

If I print the variable I can see that the value is stored.
I can see that `wpa_supplicant` is indeed started.

However when I check the `poll()` value I am getting `255` instead of `None`

```
print self.wpa_sup.poll()
```

When I am stopping the process I do it like so:

```
self.wpa_sup.terminate()
self.wpa_sup.wait()
self.wpa_sup=None
```

Sometimes (a lot of the time) it works, I can stop and start the process, read the value from `poll()` successfully, however it appears to be unreliable. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: If `poll()` is returning 255, it means your process exited with status 255. Try reading its stdout/err to figure out why (remove `stdout=open('/dev/null','w')`)

Comment: Off topic: there exists [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks, didn't know that existed. I have found the problem, will reply to the answer Sebastian gave.

Comment: But `os.devnull` already exists in 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

> I can see that `wpa_supplicant` is indeed started.

if `.poll()` returns a non-`None` value; it means the process is *dead* and moreover it is *reaped* already (the status is read) i.e., you won't see anything in the process table. If you see something after `.poll() == 255`; it means that you are looking at a different process e.g., the child process started by `Popen()` might have started a grandchild process in turn and `wpa_supplicant` exited while the grandchild continues to run or you might see some unrelated to your script process. Compare `wpa_supplicant.pid` with what you see in the process table, to find out which scenario you are observing (if they are close then the former is more likely than the latter).

The meaning of the specific return code depends on a command e.g., [`ssh` returns `255` in case of an error](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) (otherwise it returns the exit status of the remote command that it runs -- [`255` indicates wrong argument to the `exit` builtin in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/exit_status) and therefore it is less likely that the remote program produces it). Remove `stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w')`, to see errors as [@Andrea Corbellini suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200176/subprocess-poll-returning-wrong-value/35203041#comment58119031_35200176).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I have tracked it down. The code was running in a daemon and this had silently restarted which was causing issues. Fixing the problem with the daemon restarting solved the issue.